# Mono 3 needs gluezilla for web forms on linux (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: .net, winforms, mono, mozilla

Gluezilla, xul and such old mozilla stuffs seems not to be part of latest Ubuntu releases (at least starting 12.04)
I tried to find source code and all dependencies for gluezilla... without much success for now.

How are you guys doing to have web forms forking with mono2 or 3 on modern Ubuntu linux?

[EDIT]
After some more researches, I've tried to compile gluezilla from GIT using mozzila's SDK : https://github.com/mono/gluezilla

This is still not compiling because of missing files:

```
Linux0:/opt/src/gluezilla$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/src/gluezilla'
Making all in build
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/src/gluezilla/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/src/gluezilla/build'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/src/gluezilla/src'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DXPCOM_GLUE -DXPCOM_GLUE_NEEDS_NSPR -fno-rtti -fshort-wchar -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/nspr   -I../build/include -DXUL_VERSION=2  -I/opt/src/gluezilla/build/gecko-sdk/include -g -O2  -MT SecurityWarningsDialogs.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/SecurityWarningsDialogs.Tpo -c -o SecurityWarningsDialogs.lo SecurityWarningsDialogs.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DXPCOM_GLUE -DXPCOM_GLUE_NEEDS_NSPR -fno-rtti -fshort-wchar -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/nspr -I../build/include -DXUL_VERSION=2 -I/opt/src/gluezilla/build/gecko-sdk/include -g -O2 -MT SecurityWarningsDialogs.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/SecurityWarningsDialogs.Tpo -c SecurityWarningsDialogs.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/SecurityWarningsDialogs.o
In file included from SecurityWarningsDialogs.h:16:0,
                 from SecurityWarningsDialogs.cpp:13:
interfaces.h:44:34: fatal error: widget/nsIBaseWindow.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [SecurityWarningsDialogs.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/src/gluezilla/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/src/gluezilla'
make: *** [all] Error 2


Linux0:/opt/src/gluezilla$ find . -name nsIBaseWindow.h
Linux0:/opt/src/gluezilla$
```

Comment: AFAIU it's WindowsForms's WebBrowser widget the one that might depend on this, not WebForms!